# Apply single sign-on for computers not in ActiveDirectory domain

Tags: apache, active-directory, single-sign-on, windows-authentication, kerberos

I have one Windows AD server, 
and one Linux server which runs Apache and Subversion, 
also have one Windows server runs .net web application which use Windows Authentication.

I already configured out how apply Kerberos or GSSAPI to auth subversion users with AD credentials, and the users use computers which joined domain won't prompt a window ask for user and password when access .net web app and svn.

But these users who are not join domain always prompt a window ask for user and password both of web app and svn twice, I want to share login credential for the two applications, how can I apply?

Thanks.

krb5.conf:

```
[logging]
 default = FILE:/var/log/krb5libs.log
 kdc = FILE:/var/log/krb5kdc.log
 admin_server = FILE:/var/log/kadmind.log

[libdefaults]
 default_realm = SCRCUTEST.COM
 forwardable = true
 dns_lookup_realm = false
 dns_lookup_kdc = true
 rdns = false

[realms]
 SCRCUTEST.COM = {
  kdc = astest.scrcutest.com
  admin_server = astest.scrcutest.com
 }


[domain_realm]
 .scrcutest.com = SCRCUTEST.COM
  scrcutest.com = SCRCUTEST.COM
```

resolv.conf:

```
domain scrcutest.com
nameserver 10.16.0.37
```

http.conf:

```
   <Location /svn>
    DAV svn
    SVNParentPath /data/bb_bak/PV/access

    SVNListParentPath On
    SVNAutoVersioning On

    AuthType Kerberos
    AuthName "Input AD account"
    KrbAuthRealms SCRCUTEST.COM 
    KrbServiceName HTTP
    Krb5Keytab /etc/httpd/conf/kerberos.keytab
    KrbMethodNegotiate On
    KrbVerifyKDC Off
    KrbMethodK5Passwd Off
    KrbSaveCredentials on 
    Require valid-user
   </Location>
```

Comment: Can you edit your question to include the Kerberos stanza inside your Apache configuration file on the Linux server?

Comment: @T-Heron How you do know that this is a Linux server?

Comment: Wait...something doesn't seem right.  How are AD users able to SSO into Apache in the first place without the path to the keytab specified in httpd.conf?  Looks like you are missing a line which should look something like this:  _GssapiCredStore keytab:/path/to/httpd.keytab_

Comment: @T-Heron GSSAPI will search /etc/krb5.keytab by default, also if I use Krb5Keytab /etc/kerberos.keytab got the same result

Comment: @T-Heron I think used ip address in link caused this problem, today I use domain name as link to access and got this error:gss_accept_sec_context() failed: An unsupported mechanism was requested, I already added into intranet sites and enabled auto login of security settings in IE. From access_log I can see the client which joined domain access return 200, but the client not join domain return 401 381

Comment: Fair enough on GSSAPI searching /etc/krb5.keytab by default.  I am using an older Kerberos module on HTTPD which is requiring a specific path.  Anyway, with a Kerberos-protected web service all web browsers will get an HTTP 401 right up front, but AD domain-joined clients having correctly configured IE security settings will be able to negotiate Kerberos SSO into the server and silently authenticate.  However, non-AD domain joined clients using IE _won't_ be able to negotiate Kerberos SSO - which is by design.  IE will pop-up a Basic Auth dialog box at this point instead which is expected.

Comment: @T-Heron , Yes it will prompt window. I want the clients not join domain just input username and password only once when they already login another windows auth web app with prompt window ask for password. Because I have two window auth web app share the same machine key and user not need login in twice with these web app, I want apply with Kerberos auth, Is that possible? If not, then I can close it.

Comment: I understand that you don't want the user auth dialog box popping up twice.  But I'm afraid this question has become too broad for the SO format.  I am unable to help you any further.

Comment: @T-Heron, OK, thanks, I should close this question.

Comment: @T-Heron, OK, thanks, I should close this question.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

SSO not applicable if not join domain or should use a central authorize server